# Date exception when trying to use date method

Tags: java, date

I have defined a object model where one of the array elements is a string

```
public static String[] columnNames6
          = {"Total Shares",
             "Total Calls",
             "Call Strike",
             "Call Premium",
             "Call Expiry"
            };

public static Object[][] data6
= {
         { new Double(0), new Double(0), new Double(0), new Double(0),"dd/mm/yyyy"},
       };
```

I then use the following code to get the date so that I can use the data method but having
no joy - Can someone please tell me why it is throwing an exception after I do this

```
String ExpiryDate = (String)GV.data6[0][4];
System.out.println("DATE STRING IS:   " + ExpiryDate);

Date EndOptionDate = new Date(ExpiryDate); // SOMETHING WRONG HERE even though it compiles okay

//Get Todays's Date
  Date TodaysDate = new Date();

  //Calculate Days Option Expiry
 long DaysDifference = EndOptionDate.getTime() - TodaysDate.getTime();
```

Would really appreciate some help as really stuck not sure how I should code the 
line in bold - new to java, so please excuses my lack of knowledge looked at tutorials
can't seem to move forward.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: The functional requirement is not clear. Please clarify. What do you want to do with "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Comment: The convention is that class names start with capital letters and variable names do not.

Comment: just to let you know just because something compiles correctly doesn't mean it will run correctly.  Take for example, I write a program that reads past the contents of an array or datareader.  The code compiles fine but when I run it an exception is thrown.  Just so you know that compiled code is not always good code.

Comment: As Balus and others have mentioned... it's not a problem that you have a string you want to turn into a date.  The problem is that the string in your array is "dd/mm/yyyy".  That string doesn't contain any date information, only formatting information.  You need to have a string like "07/01/2011" to create a date from.  Your "dd/mm/yyyy" string can be used, as Jon mentioned to interpret the date string in your array.  Short explanation:  your array string needs to look like similar to this: "07/01/2011".  I hope that helps clear up your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

ExpiryDate is a string try changing it to a date, its deprecated

`Date(String s) 
          Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s).`

Here's an example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date today = df.parse("25/12/2010");            

System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today));
```

Comment: The string value in the code is actually a date pattern, not a fullworthy date string like "07/01/2011". So the question makes even less sense.

Comment: @BalusC- Just noticed that, it doesn't seem to make sense.  @Simon Andi please clarify the requirements.

Comment: Hi Guys, I have a abstract table model that I read a date in using a pop calendar. I then need to get that future date and calculate the amount of days from todays current date the future date is stored as a string in GV.data6[0][4] so sorry not too sure what you are asking me

Answer (score 0):

As said by JonH, you should use `DateFormat.parse` instead of `new Date(String)`. Beside, your calculation of date difference is probably not good either:

```
//Calculate Days Option Expiry
long DaysDifference    = EndOptionDate.getTime() - TodaysDate.getTime();
```

Will give you the difference in milliseconds between the two dates, not in days. You can use [`TimeUnit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) like this to obtain the day difference:

```
long dayDiff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(EndOptionDate.getTime() - TodaysDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks gabuzo try I will try that

Comment: toDays() is not a static method.  You need an enumeration instance:  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(...)

Comment: Sorry nothing has worked - All I need to know is how do I convert my string ExpiryDate to a date having dd/MM/yyyy format please

Comment: @Simon what do you mean by *convert my string ExpiryDate to a date having dd/MM/yyyy format*?

Comment: The conversion is still wrong, it has to be TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(...).  If you call TimeUnit.DAYS.toDays(...) it in turn calls TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(dt, TimeUnit.DAYS)  which converts a duration of days to a duration of days :)  But I love this utility class, great to mention.

Comment: DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); String ExpiryDate = (String)GV.data6[0][4]; Date EndOptionDate = df.parse(ExpiryDate); this is not working Expirydate is a string I want it as a date - it's as simple as that how do I do it please?

Comment: According to your code, ExpiryDate is data6[0][4] and it is definitely a String, not a Date. That's waht df.parse is doing: converting the String to a Date. Beside if data6[0][4] actually contains "dd/MM/yyyy" it is not a date at all.

Comment: Date convertedDate = null; DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); try{ String dateString = (String)GV.data6[0][4]; System.out.println("Array Date data6[0][4] : " + dateString); convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString); } catch (ParseException e ) { Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); } Date EndOptionDate = convertedDate;  convertedDate is null why?

Comment: @simon read my comment underneath your question.  As long as the value stored in GV.data[0][4] is "dd/mm/yyyy" this will never work.  Change that string in your array to "07/01/2011" and try the code to see the difference.

Comment: I have changed it to to what you have said please see my code public static Object[][] data6 = { { new Double(0), new Double(0), new Double(0), new Double(0),"01/01/2010"}, }; and it still says that convertedDate is null?

Comment: @Simon Andi - I hope you don't think anyone is really going to help you anymore.  You're lucky we even tried to help you.  With an attitude like that you won't get anywhere in life.  And you may even be banned from the site.  Good luck kiddo.